# How can i apply invisible background to a control on panel? (C#)

Tags: c#

TransparencyKey is not working when applied to a Control which is on a panel, the panel's invisible background is working.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 1);
        panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 1);
        button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

button1 is the Control on panel1. button1 still has its original backcolor (30,30,30)

Comment: You need to learn about (the very limited and actually faked) transparency in Winforms. Only when understand it you will be able to design a working solution. We can't help because we don't know what you want to achieve. The rules have been explained here ~10k+ times..

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [Color.FromArgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netframework-4.7.2) you are currently calling the method using the "RGB" overload - the values you're specifying are only populating the "RGB" part of the colour and ignoring the "A" or "alpha" part. You need to use the overload that accepts four arguments:

```
button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Notice the `0` at the begining - this is the alpha property, setting it to `0` makes the colour transparent. The clue is in the method name - "ARGB" - which denotes the order in which to specify the arguments.

From MS Docs:

> `FromArgb(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)`
>
> Creates a Color structure from the four ARGB component (alpha, red,
>   green, and blue) values. Although this method allows a 32-bit value to
>   be passed for each component, the value of each component is limited
>   to 8 bits.

Comment: @JaanSuur What does your `foreach` look like?

Comment: foreach(Control b in this.controls)

Comment: if(b is Button)

Comment: @JaanSuur Please update your question with the `foreach` code under a heading called "Update"